# Is there a dataset, database or API as large as WorldCat that allows for search by library of congress call number?

Tags: databases

Is there a raw dataset, database or API as large as WorldCat that allows for search by library of congress call number?

As far as possible I need to query all the works in the world. At least every book or monograph, or title that has been given an LOC call number. As for journals, congresses, journal articles, fresh research etc., I can exclude them. I don't need 100% everything, but something as large Worldcat. Hence, a single university library, as large as it may be, may not be sufficient.

I need to input some call number eg. Q179, and get all the titles under that call number. Is there such a thing? Preferably free also, but if really no choice, I am ok with subscription needed or need to purchase

Comment: Why can't you use the library of congress catalogue itself? It should include all books that have an LOC call number by definition. API: https://www.loc.gov/apis/

Answer (score 1):

WorldCat has two different interfaces. One allows you to search by LC Classification and one does not.

The first interface is the public one you get from https://www.worldcat.org/ :

[image: worldcat public]

This interface's Advanced Search does not have an option to search LC Classification or call numbers:

[image: worldcat public advanced search]

The second interface, OCLC FirstSearch, is available through subscription via your local academic or public library. You will need to access it from your academic institution or public library and log in with your institutional credentials or your library card:

[image: OCLC FirstSearch]

This interface's Expert Search has an option to search the Library of Congress Call No.:

[image: OCLC FirstSearch expert search]

Type `Q179` into the "Search for" box, select `Library of Congress Call No.` from the "Indexed in" dropdown, and click Search.

Results:

[image: OCLC FirstSearch expert search results]

Answer (score 0):

Yes but no.

Yes: You can search the LC catalog by LC Classification number (e.g. Q179).

No: However, the LC catalog reminds one: "Please note: The Library of Congress does not keep a copy of every title ever published."

How to search the LC catalog by LC Classification number:

1. Navigate to the catalog at https://catalog.loc.gov/
2. To the right of the search box, click "Search options" > "Keyword Search"
   [image: Search options / Keyword Search]
3. In the next page, to the right of the search box, click "ALL" and change this to "EXPERT (use index codes and operators)"
   [image: EXPERT (use index codes and operators)]
4. Note the Keyword Search Tips below the search box.

   a. The tips tell you that the wildcard for one or more characters is the question mark.

   b. The tips also include a link to a help page describing the [special index codes](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/ui/en_US/htdocs/help/indexDesc.html#names).

   c. The [list of index codes](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/ui/en_US/htdocs/help/index_code.html) is on a separate help page.
5. Using the tips and the help pages, you can form this query: `0500 Q179?` which will return any items in the LC catalog where the LC Classification number starts with Q179, e.g. `Q179.98 .S53 1985 FT MEADE`. If you want Q179 (or any other class) exactly, then don't use the `?`. You can also use `050A` instead of `0500`.

You can get even fancier by combining additional index codes, but this should get you started.

*Caveat: LC call numbers may vary from library to library. Usually the variance is in the details at the end of the number that doesn't affect your use case (e.g. a different year, or a local shelving notation), but some libraries that do original cataloging (vs. copy cataloging) may have arrived at a different classification entirely (by choosing a different main subject), or the cuttering (the .S53 in the example above) may be different. This is increasingly rare as most libraries now just copy the call number they're given and possibly add some local information, but it's a possibility to be aware of.*